# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline does not work through nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.1, thin, asset-pipeline

I am upgrading a Rails 3.0 application to Rails 3.1, and the asset pipeline is not working in development. I am using thin with an nginx reverse proxy.

For example

```
javascript_include_tag 'application' # => <script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And with curl...

```
$ curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" "http://myapp.dev/javascripts/application.js" -o /dev/null
404
$ curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" "http://myapp.dev/assets/application.js" -o /dev/null
404
```

But when I hit thin directly instead of through nginx, I get what I would expect:

```
javascript_include_tag 'application' # => <script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Does it work?

```
$ curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" "http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js" -o /dev/null
200
```

Yep! Why might this be the case?

Here is an excerpt from my nginx configuration: https://gist.github.com/1163638

Happy to provide more information, just ask!

Comment: Your original example of it generating `/javascripts` rather than `/assets` indicates a bigger problem is afoot. Are you sure you got this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you modify your development environment file? By default the asset pipeline work is happening only in production.

Comment: For some reason I had config.serve_static_assets = false in my development.rb. Flipping this resolved the problem.

Comment: Once you are satisfied with the setup you might want to switch it back off in the development environment. There is no good reason to leave it on there.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely that you need to precompile the assets.  Try running

```
rake assets:precompile
```

This is due to the fact that nginx will just blindly try to serve the assets that it is supposed to, unlike a ruby server, which will check for existence, and compile if they don't exist.

I would suggest watching Ryan Bates' [screencast on the subject](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline).

Edit:

As far as I know, there is no way to make nginx pass the request off to the backend if the file doesn't exist, however I'm not very familiar with configuring nginx, so that would probably be a good question to ask on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Can you elaborate over the 'blindly try to serve'? Isn't there a way to make Nginx forward this queries to rails before sending a 404?

Comment: Presumably you could put your ruby server in your `try_files` clause.